# Process is Whitelisted - App crashes when receiving data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing a very big problem when receiving data from Firebase.
I want in a method to receive the targets and other methods to receive the users position.

[image: This is my database]

This is my code:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase,mDatabase2;
LocationHelper locationHelpry;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    mDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child("targets");

    ReceiveTargets();
    RecieveLocation();

}

private void ReceiveTargets(){
    Log.i("ttt","1st created");

    mDatabase2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.i("ttt","2nd Created");
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                LocationHelper locationHelper = new LocationHelper();
                locationHelper = ds.getValue(LocationHelper.class);

                Log.i("ttt", "rrr"+ds.getChildrenCount());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is displaying:

```
E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
```

My manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: What is not working when using that code?